# Rails trigger rebuild of specific asset on change

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Due to [an issue in the angular-rails-templates gem](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/93), I've adopted one of the recommended workarounds in my repo [here](https://github.com/leonstafford/booklist/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/templates.js.erb) and [here](https://github.com/leonstafford/booklist/blob/master/config/initializers/angular_templates.rb).

The basic premise works - when I modify any of the JS templates, it triggers a deletion of the cache folder.

What is not happening, is the dynamically generated Angular template at `app/assets/javascripts/templates.js.erb` is not being recompiled in the same process. I still have to restart the rails server to see the changes.

How can I get that file recompiling as part of the same process?

**Generate Angular template cache** *(works on rails server start only)*

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('templates', []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    <%
      environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper }
      app_root  = File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
      templates = File.join(app_root, %w{templates ** *.html.haml})
      Dir.glob(templates).each do |f|
        key  = f.gsub(%r(^#{app_root}/templates/), '')
        key.gsub!('.haml', '')
        html = Tilt::HamlTemplate.new(f).render
        template = html.squish
    %>
      $templateCache.put("<%= key  %>", "<%= escape_javascript(template) %>");
  <% end %>
  }]);
}());
```

**Listen for changes to any JS templates**

```
require 'fileutils'

if Rails.env.development?
  cache_path = Rails.root.join('tmp/cache/assets/development')
  FileUtils.rm_rf(cache_path)

  listener = Listen.to(Rails.root.join('app/assets/templates')) do |modified, added, removed|
    puts 'CLEARING NG TEMPLATE CACHE'
    # clearing cache
    FileUtils.rm_rf(cache_path)
  end
  listener.start
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails default cache [FileStore](http:///classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/FileStore.html) uses additional memory store to save on file I/O. From there Rails keeps serving you the old content even when there are no cache files or directory.

To clean the cache completely you should invoke the following statement within same server process.

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

Therefore you listener code should look like this:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  listener = Listen.to(Rails.root.join('app/assets/templates')) do |modified, added, removed|
    puts 'CLEARING NG TEMPLATE CACHE'
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
  listener.start
end
```

If you change these templates often then probably there will be a lot of create/delete file cycles with the default cache. To avoid that you could try to switch it to pure memory cache. Add this line to your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store
```